# Build Android 5.0 error: external/chromium_org/v8/src/counters.h:445:6: internal compiler error: Segmentation fault

Tags: android, c++, c

Build Android 5.0 error on Ubuntu 15.04 :

```
target thumb C++: v8_tools_gyp_v8_base_gyp <= external/chromium_org/v8/src/elements-kind.cc
target thumb C++: v8_tools_gyp_v8_base_gyp <= external/chromium_org/v8/src/elements.cc
target thumb C++: v8_tools_gyp_v8_base_gyp <= external/chromium_org/v8/src/execution.cc
target thumb C++: v8_tools_gyp_v8_base_gyp <= external/chromium_org/v8/src/extensions/externalize-string-extension.cc
target thumb C++: v8_tools_gyp_v8_base_gyp <= external/chromium_org/v8/src/extensions/free-buffer-extension.cc
target thumb C++: v8_tools_gyp_v8_base_gyp <= external/chromium_org/v8/src/extensions/gc-extension.cc
target thumb C++: v8_tools_gyp_v8_base_gyp <= external/chromium_org/v8/src/extensions/statistics-extension.cc
target thumb C++: v8_tools_gyp_v8_base_gyp <= external/chromium_org/v8/src/extensions/trigger-failure-extension.cc
target thumb C++: v8_tools_gyp_v8_base_gyp <= external/chromium_org/v8/src/factory.cc
target thumb C++: v8_tools_gyp_v8_base_gyp <= external/chromium_org/v8/src/fast-dtoa.cc
target thumb C++: v8_tools_gyp_v8_base_gyp <= external/chromium_org/v8/src/field-index.cc
target thumb C++: v8_tools_gyp_v8_base_gyp <= external/chromium_org/v8/src/fixed-dtoa.cc
target thumb C++: v8_tools_gyp_v8_base_gyp <= external/chromium_org/v8/src/flags.cc
target thumb C++: v8_tools_gyp_v8_base_gyp <= external/chromium_org/v8/src/frames.cc
target thumb C++: v8_tools_gyp_v8_base_gyp <= external/chromium_org/v8/src/full-codegen.cc
target thumb C++: v8_tools_gyp_v8_base_gyp <= external/chromium_org/v8/src/func-name-inferrer.cc
In file included from external/chromium_org/v8/src/heap.h:12:0,
                 from external/chromium_org/v8/src/elements.h:10,
                 from external/chromium_org/v8/src/objects-inl.h:16,
                 from external/chromium_org/v8/src/v8.h:39,
                 from external/chromium_org/v8/src/func-name-inferrer.cc:5:
external/chromium_org/v8/src/counters.h:445:6: internal compiler error: Segmentation fault
   SC(keyed_call_generic_smi_dict, V8.KeyedCallGenericSmiDict)         \
      ^
external/chromium_org/v8/src/counters.h:655:16: note: in definition of macro 'SC'
   StatsCounter name##_;
                ^
external/chromium_org/v8/src/counters.h:657:3: note: in expansion of macro 'STATS_COUNTER_LIST_2'
   STATS_COUNTER_LIST_2(SC)
   ^
Please submit a full bug report,
with preprocessed source if appropriate.
See <http://source.android.com/source/report-bugs.html> for instructions.
build/core/binary.mk:617: recipe for target '/home/victor/android/system/out/target/product/shamu/obj/STATIC_LIBRARIES/v8_tools_gyp_v8_base_gyp_intermediates/v8/src/func-name-inferrer.o' failed
make: *** [/home/victor/android/system/out/target/product/shamu/obj/STATIC_LIBRARIES/v8_tools_gyp_v8_base_gyp_intermediates/v8/src/func-name-inferrer.o] Error 1
make: *** Waiting for unfinished jobs....
```

This "internal compiler error: Segmentation fault" occurred in different module every time.

Comment: *Common toolchain + popular source code + different internal compiler error every time* makes me suspect that your CPU is overheating or perhaps your RAM is dying.

Comment: @DrewDormann Isn't the GCC compiler's fault?